# Javascript - how to check what the background image is

Tags: javascript, background-image

I want to check what the background image is in Javascripot. I tried to do this:

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage == "image.jpg") {
    //code
}
```

but that doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `backgroundImage` property in javascript uses the CSS syntax.

So, to test for the background image, you would test against `url('image.jpeg')`.

Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage == "url('image.jpg')") {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate test, to make sure you're not getting type errors too:

```
var backImgUrlTest = function(elem, imgUrl){ 
  return elem && elem.backgoundImage.replace(/^url\(('|")|('|")\)$/g, "") === imgUrl;
};

if(backImgUrlTest(document.getElementById(id), "image.jpg")){
    /* Code here */
}
```

Comment: what is that first part doing?

Comment: You're making a validation function. It takes an element and a string representing the imageUrl, makes sure the element exists, takes the elem.style.backgroundImage and uses a regexp replace to remove the enclosing url(' and ') (or if double quotes)

Comment: Does my edited comment make sense

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly what it does :) is the regex confusing?

Comment: So what would I put into each of the variables? (elem and imgUrl)

Comment: elem is an element and imgUrl is a string for the desired image string. See the line in my answer with an 'if' in it for an example invocation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48627/discussion-between-cpc-and-enjoys-turtles)